# How do I display PHP form values on the confirmation page?

Tags: php, forms

I have created a simple form that emails the entered values to a designated email.

In addition I would like to display the entered / selected values on the confirmation page. I am using the following code:

```
echo '<h2>Thank you for Registering</h2>
        <h3>You have registered for the following classes</h3>
        <p>9:10 to 10:00am: "$email9_11" <br />
             10:10 to 11:00am: "$email10_11"<br />
             11:10 to 12:00:  "$email11_12"<br />
             12:10 to 1:00: "$email12_1"</p>
        <p>We look forward to seeing you October 31, 2010</p>';
```

This is how it displays:

> Thank you for Registering
>    You have registered for the following classes
>
> 9:10 to 10:00am: "$email9_11"
>   10:10 to 11:00am: "$email10_11"
>   11:10 to 12:00: "$email11_12"
>   12:10 to 1:00: "$email12_1"
>
> We look forward to seeing you
>   October 31, 2010

Here are the variables:

```
$emailFromName = $_POST['name'];
$emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$emailFromPhone = $_POST['phone'];
$email9_11 = $_POST['9-10'];
$email10_11 = $_POST['10-11'];
$email11_12 = $_POST['11-12'];
$email12_1 = $_POST['12-1'];
```

I would appreciate help getting this to display properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using single quotes for your `echo`, in which case variables will not be expanded. Use double quotes instead: (and of course escape the double quotes inside your text)

```
echo "<h2>Thank you for Registering</h2>
        <h3>You have registered for the following classes</h3>
        <p>9:10 to 10:00am: \"$email9_11\" <br />
             10:10 to 11:00am: \"$email10_11\"<br />
             11:10 to 12:00:  \"$email11_12\"<br />
             12:10 to 1:00: \"$email12_1\"</p>
        <p>We look forward to seeing you October 31, 2010</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your echo in double-quotes if you want to output variable values inline instead of variable names.

```
$var = "foo";
echo '$var'; //Outputs $var
echo "$var"; //Outputs foo
```

You'll also need to escape `\"` the double-quotes inside the content.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good principles here. The example above was clearer for a php newb. Thank you.